# error when trying to retrieve from Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I've noticed that this line is causing problem

```
NSManagedObject *newContact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LoginViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I selected the lines and pressed `CTRL+K` to give them coding-look :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to link CoreData framework in your project settings.